# Clearing Check Box on New Record, MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, checkbox

I am teaching myself VBA in MS Access. I want to clear a check box when a new record is created. In other words, if the record is new, I want the check box to revert back to a unchecked state.

I tried:

```
If Me.NewRecord = True Then
  Me.checkbox = False
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Is your form bound to a table or query? Is your checkbox bound yo a field (column)?

Comment: @Remou. The form is bound to a table, but the checkbox is not bound to a field.

Comment: Which event are you using? Does the code run? Set a breakpoint (F9) to check.

Comment: I tried it on the after update event on the checkbox and the before insert event on the form

Comment: Use the Current event. BTW, I hope your checkbox is not called checkbox.

Comment: @Remou. Thanks for the suggestion. The current event solved my problem. If you submit it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to use the right event on Access forms and even more so in Access reports. In this case, the Current event would seem to be appropriate.

You might like to look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx